# PHP preg_replace only numbers

Tags: php, numbers, preg-replace

I have a string and I want to get only number witch is between 5 and 7 charts.
Here my problem:

```
$string = "Test 1 97779 test";
if(strlen(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string)) >= 5 && strlen(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $parts[7])) <= 7) {
    $var = preg_replace("/[^\d-]+/", "", $string);
}
```

Result is: 19779, but I want only 97779.
If someone have any suggestion I will be very glad. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend is [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
if(preg_match('/\b\d{5,7}\b/', $str, $out))
  $var = $out[0];
```

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `\d{5,7}` in between 5 to 7 digits [\d](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/513801)

Comment: God bless you, I will send you beer! Thank you, you are great! :)

Comment: one little question how I can get if $string = "Tes97779 test";

Comment: @diank In this case use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `/(?<!\d)\d{5,7}(?!\d)/` like in this [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rE9vZ6/1). This one matches 5 to 7 digits not bordering at another digit.

Comment: @diank If you want to cut off the first ten, just [remove the lookahead part (?!\d)](https://regex101.com/r/rE9vZ6/3)

Comment: @diank Yer welcome! Also see the [regex faq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5527985) if interested.